# How does htaccess / htpasswd effect file writing?

Tags: .htaccess

I've been developing a website on a local web server and I'm pretty happy with it. I'm about ready to deploy it but I've been looking at how to limit folder access via htaccess. My concern is I grab some php variables from a document on the web server and I'm worried that by denying htaccess ill also prevent the php file from reading and writing to this document. Is this the case? If so how would I go about setting up a hierarchy in which my php can read and write to my document but people can't access the folder that its in?

Comment: Realize that access via HTTP and access via file system are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a means to configure a server on a per-directory basis.

If you are going to be writing files using PHP, then it is going to be doing so using the file system (unless you are using HTTP PUT or similar, but you'd know if you were), so the server configuration is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Apache will simply forward your requests to the PHP interpreter. Once the request is past Apache, all rewrites/folder restrictions have already been validated, which means PHP never knows about them (and it shouldn't).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess is a webserver restriction, if you can access the page, then PHP doesn't care if you have it or not, so you can `fopen` / edit your files from PHP without problems. Of course if you write your file to a (different) directory that is htaccess protected, the user will have to insert the password to read it